# Flink Task Manager Suddenly Crashed

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Flink TM suddenly got crashed after 3 months of running with the below error stack trace.

```
2021-12-05 07:22:05,369 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Task 'GlobalWindowAggregate(groupBy=[org, $f4], window=[HOP(slice_end=[$slice_end], size=[15 min], slide=[1 min])], select=[org, $f4, COUNT(distinct$0 count$0) AS $f2, COUNT(count1$1) AS window_start, start('w$) AS window_end]) -> Calc(select=[window_start, window_end, org, $f4, $f2 AS $f4_0]) (1/24)#6' did not react to cancelling signal for 30 seconds, but is stuck in method:
 org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.BufferManager.notifyBufferAvailable(BufferManager.java:296)
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.LocalBufferPool.fireBufferAvailableNotification(LocalBufferPool.java:507)
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.LocalBufferPool.recycle(LocalBufferPool.java:494)
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.LocalBufferPool.recycle(LocalBufferPool.java:460)
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.NetworkBuffer.deallocate(NetworkBuffer.java:182)
org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.handleRelease(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:110)
org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:100)
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.NetworkBuffer.recycleBuffer(NetworkBuffer.java:156)
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.BufferManager$AvailableBufferQueue.addExclusiveBuffer(BufferManager.java:399)
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.BufferManager.recycle(BufferManager.java:200)
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.NetworkBuffer.deallocate(NetworkBuffer.java:182)
org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.handleRelease(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:110)
org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:100)
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.NetworkBuffer.recycleBuffer(NetworkBuffer.java:156)
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.serialization.SpillingAdaptiveSpanningRecordDeserializer.getNextRecord(SpillingAdaptiveSpanningRecordDeserializer.java:95)
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.emitNext(AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.java:95)
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:66)
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:423)
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$$Lambda$615/1465249724.runDefaultAction(Unknown Source)
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:204)
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:681)
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.executeInvoke(StreamTask.java:636)
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$$Lambda$1480/994476387.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runWithCleanUpOnFail(StreamTask.java:647)
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:620)
org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:779)
org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:566)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2021-12-05 07:22:05,370 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.slot.TaskSlotTableImpl [] - Free slot TaskSlot(index:7, state:ALLOCATED, resource profile: ResourceProfile{cpuCores=2.0000000000000000, taskHeapMemory=2.656gb (2852126690 bytes), taskOffHeapMemory=0 bytes, managedMemory=1.875gb (2013265950 bytes), networkMemory=128.000mb (134217728 bytes)}, allocationId: 2b2d5beb481130d88a1eaaa0d3be2f7d, jobId: a5ed6a11efac85d315195eb9e7534316).
2021-12-05 07:22:05,370 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Attempting to fail task externally GlobalWindowAggregate(groupBy=[org, $f4], window=[HOP(slice_end=[$slice_end], size=[15 min], slide=[1 min])], select=[org, $f4, COUNT(distinct$0 count$0) AS $f2, COUNT(count1$1) AS window_start, start('w$) AS window_end]) -> Calc(select=[window_start, window_end, org, $f4, $f2 AS $f4_0]) (1/24)#6 (5e34a8de7bcff882f37c073f250c2594).
2021-12-05 07:22:05,370 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Task GlobalWindowAggregate(groupBy=[org, $f4], window=[HOP(slice_end=[$slice_end], size=[15 min], slide=[1 min])], select=[org, $f4, COUNT(distinct$0 count$0) AS $f2, COUNT(count1$1) AS window_start, start('w$) AS window_end]) -> Calc(select=[window_start, window_end, org, $f4, $f2 AS $f4_0]) (1/24)#6 is already in state CANCELING
2021-12-05 07:22:05,372 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.slot.TaskSlotTableImpl [] - Free slot TaskSlot(index:7, state:RELEASING, resource profile: ResourceProfile{cpuCores=2.0000000000000000, taskHeapMemory=2.656gb (2852126690 bytes), taskOffHeapMemory=0 bytes, managedMemory=1.875gb (2013265950 bytes), networkMemory=128.000mb (134217728 bytes)}, allocationId: 2b2d5beb481130d88a1eaaa0d3be2f7d, jobId: a5ed6a11efac85d315195eb9e7534316).
2021-12-05 07:22:15,362 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner      [] - Terminating TaskManagerRunner with exit code 1.
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Unexpected failure during runtime of TaskManagerRunner.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.runTaskManager(TaskManagerRunner.java:382) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.lambda$runTaskManagerProcessSecurely$3(TaskManagerRunner.java:413) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.runTaskManagerProcessSecurely(TaskManagerRunner.java:413) [flink-dist_2.12-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.runTaskManagerProcessSecurely(TaskManagerRunner.java:396) [flink-dist_2.12-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner.main(TaskManagerRunner.java:354) [flink-dist_2.12-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$Timeout.run(FutureUtils.java:1255) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.DirectExecutorService.execute(DirectExecutorService.java:217) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$orTimeout$15(FutureUtils.java:582) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
2021-12-05 07:22:15,365 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.TransientBlobCache             [] - Shutting down BLOB cache
2021-12-05 07:22:15,365 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.PermanentBlobCache             [] - Shutting down BLOB cache
2021-12-05 07:22:15,365 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.state.TaskExecutorLocalStateStoresManager [] - Shutting down TaskExecutorLocalStateStoresManager.
2021-12-05 07:22:15,365 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.filecache.FileCache                 [] - removed file cache directory /tmp/flink-dist-cache-9fad861a-b657-4625-a184-db126c423c2f
```

While debugging, I found Input and output buffer usage reached 100% usage on datadog dashboard.[image] [image]

Also found out that last 2 checkpoints got failed with message `Checkpoint expired before completing.` Checkpoint timeout is 2 mins.
How can I fix this issue. [image]

Comment: What is your checkpoint properties `env.getCheckpointConfig.setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1)
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setTolerableCheckpointFailureNumber(1)` ?

Comment: Max concurrent checkpoint is 1 and tolerable checkpoints is also 1

Comment: Maybe that's your problem ? You write about 2 checkpoints got failed when checkpoints failure number 1. Another question why they failed ...

Comment: both checkpoint got failed with error: checkpoint not completed in require time

Answer (score 0):

Checkpoint timeouts are generally caused by either

1. backpressure causing the checkpoint barriers to progress too slowly across the execution graph, or
2. some sort of bottleneck preventing Flink from writing fast enough to the checkpoint storage (e.g., network starvation, insufficient iops quota)

It looks like you are using unaligned checkpointing. This should help with point number 1 above, but could be causing point number 2 to be a problem, since unaligned checkpoints increase the amount of data being checkpointed (by up to about a 1GB in your case, it looks like).

You might just want to increase the checkpoint timeout. Having checkpoints timeout is almost never helpful.

But it also appears that you have significant backpressure. Figuring out what's causing that and doing something about it should help. (If you can upgrade to Flink 1.13 (or later) the improved backpressure monitoring will make this easier.) Perhaps you have data skew, or perhaps you need to scale up the cluster.

Comment: I already checked backpressure metrics, at that point of time, there was no any backpressure, only checkpoints are getting failed with error: `checkpoint not completed in require time`

Comment: I'm thinking that during the period when output buffers were 100% utilized, there was backpressure.

Comment: So what should I do, increase buffer memory or checkpoint timeout?

Comment: Increasing buffers would make things worse; do not do that. My guess is that you had a rare event that caused significant, temporary backpressure and prevented checkpointing from completing in time. I would increase the timeout. If it happens again, you might want to investigate the cause of the backpressure, and determine if it is preventable.

Comment: Also David, I don't understand why it kills Task manager, because after a restart, it works smoothly and lag also got recovered in no time, shouldn't task manager restart itself instead of getting exited

Comment: That's just how things work. The assumption is that after enough checkpoints have failed to cause the job to fail, manual intervention is the safest strategy.

Comment: David, can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70295970/flink-table-get-type-information