# Flink table get type information

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink table let's say `CREATE TABLE source(id int, name string) with (...)` and a destination table let's say `CREATE TABLE destination(id int, unique_name string) with (...)`. `unique_name` is calculated using business logic in internal flink process function.

So We can safely assume that the source schema will be exact(name and data types) same as the destination schema.
I did some low level `process` using datastream API to get `destination` datastream. It has `outputType` as `GenericType<org.apache.flink.types.Row>`. When I convert back `destination` datastream to table again, I got the below error.

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Column types of query result and sink 
for registered table 'default_catalog.default_database.destination' do not match.
Cause: Different number of columns.

Query schema: [f0: RAW('org.apache.flink.types.Row', '...')]
Sink schema:  [id: INT, name: STRING]
```

Although I'm able to resolve this issue using below code, however I want to generify this and get `RowTypeInformation` from destination `Table`. Is there any way to get `TypeInformation` from flink `Table`.

```
tableEnv.fromDataStream(destionationDataStream.map(x -> x).returns(Types.ROW(Types.Int, Types.String))
```

Answer (score 3):

The table type system is richer than `TypeInformation`. If you are ok with using internal classes, you can use `org.apache.flink.table.runtime.typeutils.ExternalTypeInfo`. It is `TypeInformation` that can be configured using Table API's `DataType`.

If you like to use officially supported API. You can declare the in and out type with `TypeInformation` and use `DataTypes.of(TypeInformation)` when calling `StreamTableEnvironment.toDataStream(..., DataType)`

Comment: I'm not calling toDataStream, Not able to understand clearly, below is my code snippet, can you help. https://www.paste.org/120818

Comment: @timo, I have used externaltypeinfo, with `ROW_NAMED`, but still code is failing in class `RowRowConverter` `toInternal` method. It is issue of column ordering.However I have added TypeInformation with fieldNames, but still it is coming  null.  `tableEnv.fromDataStream(processedDataStream.map(x => x).returns(
            Types.ROW_NAMED(destinationColumnName, destinationTypeInformation: _*)
          ))`

Comment: Error: Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Error during input conversion from external DataStream API to internal Table API data structures. Make sure that the provided data types that configure the converters are correctly declared in the schema. Affected record